# How to increase the coverage summary in jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to jasmine and karma. Facing issue in increase the coverage summary on component method.

How to increase the coverage of if-else condition present inside subscribe block?

I have called the a service method in app.component.ts file. I have to validate the response and show image according to result but coverage is not getting covered.

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'bank';
  flag: string;
  image: string;

  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/-(.*?)-/);

  constructor(private service : FlagService) {}

  ngOnit() {
    this.service.getFlag().subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.flag = res.FlagModel[0].code.match(this.regex)[1];

        if(this.flag === 'dev') {
          this.image = '../assessts/icons/dev.png'
        } else if(this.flag === 'qa') {
          this.image = '../assessts/icons/qa.png'
        } else if(this.flag === 'prod') {
          this.image = '../assessts/icons/prod.png'
        } 
      }, (error) =>{
        console.log(error);
       });

  }
}
```

**app.component.specs.ts**

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let flagServiceTest: FlagService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        HttpClient,
        HttpHandler,
        FlagService
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    flagServiceTest = TestBed.get(FlagService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should have as title 'bank'`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('bank');
  });

  it('should call subscribe method', fakeAsync(() => {
    const flagSpy = spyOn(flagServiceTest,'getFlag').and.callThrough();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.ngOnit();
    tick();
    expect(flagServiceTest.getFlag()).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(flagSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(flagSpy.calls.any()).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

expecting the below block to be included by jasmine:

```
this.service.getFlag().subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.flag = res.FlagModel[0].code.match(this.regex)[1];

        if(this.flag === 'dev') {
          this.image = '../assessts/icons/dev.png'
        } else if(this.flag === 'qa') {
          this.image = '../assessts/icons/qa.png'
        } else if(this.flag === 'prod') {
          this.image = '../assessts/icons/prod.png'
        } 
      }, (error) =>{
        console.log(error);
       });
```

Comment: you can create a mock for your FalgService, and for each if case you can simulate a return.

Comment: can you please help me how to simulate if else case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you need to create a test case for each if statement and you need to provide each time a suitable feed from your service, so I suggest that you use spies instead of referencing you real FlagService
- create a global fixture so you don't have to instantiate it for every test case
- You do not need to call **.detectChanges** since you already call ngOnInit.
  Please see the below project, that cover 100% your appComponent.
  (https://github.com/IsmailDiari/stackoverflow-anglar-jasmine-code-coverage).
  [image]

Comment: How can I access FlagModel because from FlagService observable is returning FlagModel.
Your observable is returning string.
FlagModel
`export interface Flag {
 'code': string;
 'desc': string;
}
export interface FlagModel{
 
 'flagDescription': Flag[];
 'employeeFlag': string;
 'region': Flag;
 'user': string;
} 
`

while running I am getting TypeScript: cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Comment: I can not understant your service ouput, you say that you return a FlagModel but in your subscribe it seems not.
Any way I have push a new commit to my git, it responds to what you describe in your comment.